# How can I get the index of a one-hot encoded vector without using a for-loop?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I have a signal "event_id" where only one of the bits is high at any time. I need to convert this one-hot encoded signal to an integer-value of the index.

The signals:

```vhdl
signal event_id: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal event_index: natural;
```

I know I can do this with a for-loop. This is what I'm currently doing:

```vhdl
for i in 3 downto 0 loop
    if(event_id(i) = '1') then
      event_index = i;
    end if;
end loop;
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require a for-loop or going through each bit individually? I know I could make a function with the for-loop method, but I feel like there should be a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: The problem is that VHDL doesn't have any way of knowing that your std_logic_vector is one-hot.  If you want to avoid writing your own function you could use log2 from ieee.math_real, e.g. something like `event_index <= natural(log2(real(to_integer(unsigned(event_id)))));`.  This breaks if `event_id` is not one-hot.

Comment: Importing the math library seems overkill for this. This conversion is just the kind of thing I've found myself doing more than once and a for-loop felt inappropriate. I think for now I'll still use the loop for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: what is your concern regarding the `for`-loop?

Comment: From hardware generation point of view, if you construct an index of a one-hot, you effectively cancel any effectiveness of a one-hot encoding

Comment: @mfro I just feel the for-loop is a lot of lines for a simple operation. I would like to keep the code "clean".

Comment: @OronPort Yeah, but I can't modify the source of the signal and I do need to compute the index.

Comment: @Plebala than just put the `for`-loop in a function in a package and forget about it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "simple" solution for generating the index of a one-hot vector in VHDL.

For a one-hot vector of 4 bits, thus a resulting index of 2 bits, the loop you have made is an OK solution, that is readable and does not take up too much resources in implementation.  Though it is not the smallest solution, since it does not allow the implementation size to benefit from the one-hot property, as it returns the lowest index of a set bit.  For short one-hot vectors this does not matter if the implementation is in an FPGA, since it uses quantized LUT resources.

For longer one-hot vectors the implementation will be smaller if the one-hot property is used.  This can be done with an algorithm where the index bits are generated from the one-hot vector and a mask.  A function for this is shown below.

```
-- One hot to index calculate; assuming LEN_HOT = 2 ** LEN_IDX
function hot2idx_cal(hot : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
  variable mask_v : std_logic_vector(LEN_HOT - 1 downto 0);
  variable res_v  : std_logic_vector(LEN_IDX - 1 downto 0);
begin
  for i in 0 to LEN_IDX - 1 loop
    -- Generate mask
    for j in 0 to LEN_HOT - 1 loop
      if ((j / (2 ** i)) mod 2) = 0 then
        mask_v(j) := '0';
      else
        mask_v(j) := '1';
      end if;
    end loop;
    -- Apply mask and generate bit in index
    if unsigned(hot and mask_v) = 0 then
      res_v(i) := '0';
    else
      res_v(i) := '1';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so a solution can be demonstrated.

For a globally static one hot vector array value length 4 the logic is two OR gates:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity onehot2indx is
end entity;

architecture foo of onehot2indx is
    signal event_id:    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "1000";
    signal event_index: natural;
begin
    event_index <= to_integer (
        unsigned'((event_id(3) or event_id(2)) & (event_id(3) or event_id(1)))
    );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            wait for 10 ns;
            event_id <= (others => '0');
            event_id(i) <= '1';
        end loop;
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Which produces:

[image: onehot2indx.jpg]

Think hardware description and not language problem.

For one hot vector lengths that are too tedious to readily see a truth table of inputs and outputs can be used as input to logic reduction software (e.g. espresso) as well as loop statements or case statements relying on synthesis software.

Length 4 is trivial and easy to see without a truth table.

(At one time you had to pay for licenses for arithmetic function synthesis, being cheap made you think of the logic, note how Morten referred to the resulting index value length despite depending on synthesis mapping and reduction while using a natural.)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Sorry about the incomplete example. I don't quite understand your last comment about Morten using a natural. Did he maybe edit his code to use slv?

Comment: No, it was directed at synthesis products being binary representations. Morton worked out the binary representation from the number of event_index elements. That directs a truth table with 4 inputs and 4 unique values and two outputs. Something small enough to work out in your head.